# Import data from Analysis Services cube into MS SQL database

Tags: database, service, analysis, cube

Is there a possibility to insert data from Analysis Services cube into **MS SQL database**?

At the moment I can use excel to get data from Analysis Services cube, but I want to store some data from CUBE into my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_FetchDataFromCube]

AS

BEGIN

declare @mdx_query as varchar(max), 
@open_query as nvarchar(max), 
@linked_server as varchar(max)

set @mdx_query = 'SELECT {[Measures].[col1]} ON COLUMNS,
{ [Time].[Month].[' + CONVERT(CHAR(7), GETDATE(),126) + ']} ON ROWS FROM [database]
WHERE [field].[field].[value]'

set @linked_server = 'LINKED'

set @open_query = 'SELECT DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, GETDATE())), * FROM OpenQuery 
("'+@linked_server+'",'''+ @mdx_query + ''')'

execute sp_executesql @open_query

END